# как получить id нового коммита в git-хуке update?

Tags: git, sh, githooks

Мне надо получить id нового коммита (мне нужно уведомления отправлять об изменении АПИ в список рассылки (вычисляется по спецтегу). "новый коммит" - это такой, с которым работает хук update. он ведь во время коммита работает?) в git-хуке, можно ли это сделать в git-хуке update или надо в post-commit делать? документацию читал, но не  понял... надо бы пример.

Comment: что значит "новый коммит"? и распишите пожалуйста, какой сценарий вас интересует, чтобы можно было понять, какой хук вам нужен

Comment: @vmchar мне нужно уведомления отправлять об  изменении АПИ в список рассылки (вычисляется по спецтегу). "новый коммит"  - это такой, с которым работает хук update. он ведь во время коммита работает?

Comment: так напишите в вопросе (нажав [edit]), а не в комментарии, что именно вам требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала про сам Update хук:

> This hook is run every time someone pushes something to this repository

По русски - хук отрабатывает каджый раз, когда кто-либо делает push в репозиторий.

При этом данному хуку доступны 3 параметра:

- имя ветки, в которой произошли изменения
- id (SHA-1), коммита, который был последним в ветке до обновления `$old_ref
- id (SHA-1), коммита, нового последнего коммита, которые появится в результате обновления `$new_ref`

Больше информации по хуку в [статье](https://dzone.com/articles/how-not-to-write-your-git-update-hooks) и [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git).

Далее по вашему вопросу - если уведомлять пользователя, то логиченее после того, как произошел push, а не commit. Потому что если речь идет о разработчике - хук на commit отработает еще до того, как изменения зальются на remote (а эти изменения можно забыть залить сразу или вообще не заливать специально).

Параметров из update хука вам должно хватить:
[Вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474115/how-to-find-the-tag-associated-with-a-given-git-commit), где по SHA получают тэги коммита. Вкратце, смотрите в сторону команды `git describe`.